# CSS3 transforms vs. document flow

Tags: css, animation, transform

I'd like to have a smooth open/close animation for a page's navigation, so I choose to use the CSS3 transform property.

In this example I have a nav-toggle button on the menu that will reveal the menu by pushing the content div downwards (adding a `.menu-opened` class to `#content`).

```
#content {
    transform: translate3d(0, -280, 0);
}

#content.menu-opened {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

[image]

However, CSS3 transforms don't affect the document flow (like the `height` of an element does, for instance), so, either content would be hidden, either there would be an extra-space (equal to menu's height) somewhere, in this case, at the bottom of the page.

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacalves/z35hmvwu/3/)

How to deal with that?

Comment: maybe setting menu (parent-div) height? if ypu set up a fiddle it will be easier to fix..

Comment: toggle between **height:0** and **height: auto**? this would also allow for smooth transforms/transitions?

Comment: I could set a parent div for the menu and toggle its height between 0 and auto (with no transition: height transition would be rough). and have only a smooth transition on the menu, revealing it from the top, for example, but wouldn't have a transition in the main content going down (it would just jump downwards). is that what you mean?

Comment: i made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacalves/z35hmvwu/3/)